# JPA Property Access gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table called Products in my database, and I am using JPA 2.0 to access it.

I am using JSF 2.0 on Glassfish Server.

I have my layers like this:

products.xhtml -> ProductsBackingBean.java -> ProductsDao.java -> Produtcs.Java

Here is products.xhtml :

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="product" value="#{productsBackingBean.allProducts}">
        <p:column headerText="Product Code">
            <h:outputText value="#{product.productCode}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Product Description">
            <h:outputText value="#{product.productDescription}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And here is ProductsBackinBean.java:

```
package com.tugay.maythirty.model;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

    @Named
    @SessionScoped
    public class ProductsBackingBean implements Serializable {
        @EJB private ProductsDao productsDao;
        public List<Products> getAllProducts(){
           return productsDao.getAllProducts();
        }
    }
```

And ProductsDao.Java:

```
package com.tugay.maythirty.model;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Stateful
public class ProductsDao {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init");
    }

    public List<Products> allProducts;

    public List<Products> getAllProducts() {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Persistence");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        if (allProducts == null) {
            TypedQuery<Products> typedQuery = em.createQuery("Select p from Products p", Products.class);
            allProducts = typedQuery.getResultList();
        }
        return allProducts;
    }
}
```

And here is Products.Java:

```
@Entity
public class Products {

    private String productCode;
    private String productDescription;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "productCode")
    @Id
    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "productDescription")
    @Basic
    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription.substring(0,20);
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // some hashcode here. not relevant. 
    }
}
```

So the important part is:

**return productDescription.substring(0,20);**

In my table I want to show only the first 20 chars of the Product Description. However I get an exception:

**exception
javax.servlet.ServletException
root cause
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException
root cause
javax.ejb.NoSuchObjectLocalException: The EJB does not exist. session-key: 3890c00100a81f-3a922970-0**

I must note that, when I but a breakpoint in init() method of ProductDao, I see that it is called. However when ProductBackingBean calls productDao.getAllProducts, the productDao seems to be null.

Also in the log I see that:

at com.tugay.maythirty.model.**EJB31_Generated_*ProductsDao*_Intf_***Bean*_.getAllProducts(Unknown Source)
at com.tugay.maythirty.model.ProductsBackingBean.getAllProducts(ProductsBackingBean.java:14)

**If I remove the substring(0,20) everything is fine.**

I have 2 questions:

1. What is it that I am doing wrong?
2. What is the **proper** way to get the first 20 characters to show? Should it be in ProductsTableBackingBean.java,  ProductsDao.java or directly in the Entity class as seen in here?

Comment: It seems you have "productDescription" value as null in database. Before doing subString, do null check

Comment: @Nambari If I remove the substring(0,20) everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, NPE happens if you perform any operation on null reference. So, my guess is you are getting productdescription as null.

Comment: @Nambari Thanks for your comment. But why? Is it because it is trying to apply the method before it gets the data from the database? Interesting..

Comment: It could be, with out seeing call sequence, it is hard to comment.

Comment: This problem is unrelated with JSF at all.

Comment: @KorayTugay did you debug to check if there is a product description null? or maybe it is been called before the entity has its value loaded

Comment: @fmodos Hello, I will edit my question soon. Could you please take a look after 5 - 10 minutes? I did some work on it. I will expand my explanation.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Maybe it is something with the view part? I mean the xhtml?

Comment: @KorayTugay replace the code with error by this one `return productDescription!=null ? productDescription.substring(0,20) : "";`, check if it will work by loading all the products from the DB.
`

Comment: @fmodos Hello, it works now.. But why?

Comment: @fmodos Ah.. I see. Stupid me.. There are products with null description!!! I feel very embarrassed..

Comment: @fmodos Can you please answer the question so I can select it as correct.

Comment: @KorayTugay because you might have null productDescription, the important is to make sure that it is loading right of the DB.

Comment: @KorayTugay just posted an answer with some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might have `null` `productDescription` in the database, so it is necessary to check for a `null` value before `substring` it, like the example below:

```
@javax.persistence.Column(name = "productDescription")
@Basic
public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription !=null ? productDescription.substring(0,20) : "";
}
```

But I would suggest you to keep the `getProductDescription()` intact and create a new one to return the short description, it would be:

```
    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "productDescription")
    @Basic
    public String getProductDescription() {
            return productDescription;
        }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return productDescription !=null ? productDescription.substring(0,20) : "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is triming your value at ui layer. Entity fields may be accessed before its full initialization, which leads in your case to trying triming a null value.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the bean, not the value itself. Can it be?